# What is the use of verbose in Keras while validating the model?

Tags: python, deep-learning, keras, verbose

I'm running the LSTM model for the first time.
Here is my model:

```
opt = Adam(0.002)
inp = Input(...)
print(inp)
x = Embedding(....)(inp)
x = LSTM(...)(x)
x = BatchNormalization()(x)
pred = Dense(5,activation='softmax')(x)

model = Model(inp,pred)
model.compile(....)

idx = np.random.permutation(X_train.shape[0])
model.fit(X_train[idx], y_train[idx], nb_epoch=1, batch_size=128, verbose=1)
```

What is the use of verbose while training the model?

Answer (score 374, accepted):

Check documentation for model.fit [here](https://keras.io/models/model/).

By setting verbose 0, 1 or 2 you just say how do you want to 'see' the training progress for each epoch.

`verbose=0` will show you nothing (silent)

`verbose=1` will show you an animated progress bar like this:

[image: progres_bar]

`verbose=2` will just mention the number of epoch like this:

[image]

Comment: **verbose: Integer. 0, 1, or 2. Verbosity mode. 0 = silent, 1 = progress bar, 2 = one line per epoch.**
Thanks @ank you rock..

Comment: This comment is the best answer to the question, even better than the answer being commented. Note this and try to avoid words just to make the answer longer. @rakesh, you rock.

Comment: I set 'verbose=0' and yet this annoying progress bar is still shown.  (See **model.fit(..., verbose=0) still prints stuff** (https://github.com/keras-team/tf-keras/issues/583))

Answer (score 48):

`verbose: Integer`. 0, 1, or 2. Verbosity mode.

Verbose=0 (silent)

Verbose=1 (progress bar)

```
Train on 186219 samples, validate on 20691 samples
Epoch 1/2
186219/186219 [==============================] - 85s 455us/step - loss: 0.5815 - acc: 
0.7728 - val_loss: 0.4917 - val_acc: 0.8029
Train on 186219 samples, validate on 20691 samples
Epoch 2/2
186219/186219 [==============================] - 84s 451us/step - loss: 0.4921 - acc: 
0.8071 - val_loss: 0.4617 - val_acc: 0.8168
```

Verbose=2 (one line per epoch)

```
Train on 186219 samples, validate on 20691 samples
Epoch 1/1
 - 88s - loss: 0.5746 - acc: 0.7753 - val_loss: 0.4816 - val_acc: 0.8075
Train on 186219 samples, validate on 20691 samples
Epoch 1/1
 - 88s - loss: 0.4880 - acc: 0.8076 - val_loss: 0.5199 - val_acc: 0.8046
```

Comment: Can you explain why am I not getting the expected output for differnt vakues of verbose. I'm getting same [silent] output for verbose = 0 and 2 for my file? And for verbose = 1, I'm getting progress bar only at the end of epochs like Epoch 10/10
 - 21s - loss: 0.2354 - acc: 0.9286 - val_loss: 0.2206 - val_acc: 0.9344   [==============================]
Accuracy: 0.9344 
 Error: 6.560000000000002

Comment: great answer, helped me out. Valid for tensorflow 2.2

Answer (score 13):

For `verbose` > 0, `fit` method logs:

- **loss**: value of loss function for your training data
- **acc**: accuracy value for your training data.

*Note: If regularization mechanisms are used, they are turned on to avoid overfitting.*

if `validation_data` or `validation_split` arguments are not empty, `fit` method logs:

- **val_loss**: value of loss function for your validation data
- **val_acc**: accuracy value for your validation data

*Note: Regularization mechanisms are turned off at testing time because we are using all the capabilities of the network.*

For example, using `verbose` while training the model helps to detect overfitting which occurs if your `acc` keeps improving while your `val_acc` gets worse.

Comment: What relevance is regularisation to the verbosity parameter?!

Comment: Verbose parameter has no impact on regularisation mechanisms. I'm just adding information about what is displayed if verbose is enabled (to reply to the initial question "What is the use of verbose while training the model?" => ex: avoiding overfitting by comparing acc and val_acc).

Answer (score 12):

verbose is the choice that how you want to see the output of your Nural Network while it's training.
If you set verbose = 0, It will show nothing

If you set verbose = 1, It will show the output like this
Epoch 1/200
55/55[==============================] - 10s 307ms/step - loss: 0.56 - accuracy: 0.4949

If you set verbose = 2, The output will be like
Epoch 1/200
Epoch 2/200
Epoch 3/200

Answer (score 7):

By default verbose = 1,

verbose = 1, which includes both progress bar and one line per epoch

verbose = 0, means silent

verbose = 2, one line per epoch i.e. epoch no./total no. of epochs

Answer (score 5):

The order of details provided with verbose flag are as

> Less details.... More details
>
> 0  <  2  <  1

Default is 1

For production environment, 2 is recommended

Comment: the last message in your answer is the best one, i would say.